# how can I further optimize this Python code to make it fit into the time limit?

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop

On the last coding contest, there was the following problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1916/problem/C

To solve it, I needed to run through the given array once and print the resulting array. I decided to use the For loop, at each step of which I was appending an element to the resultant list and after it I was printing the list out.

That solution exceeded the time limit, so I decided to abstain from using Append, and was populating the pre-created list instead.

That solution also exceeded the time limit, so I decided to avoid the Print part as it also has O(n) complexity, and was printing the result of each step within the For loop. However, even that did not suffice to fit into the time limit.

So, my question is "is it Python that is too slow (I did hear some people saying that Python is not a good choice for competitive programing) or I could have optimized something further to speed up my code?"

Here is the initial code I used where I was updating the list at each step of For loop and printing the resultant list once the For loop is complete:

```
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        n = int(input())
        v = list(map(int, input().split()))
        if n == 1:
            print(v[0])
        elif n == 2:
            print(v[0], int((v[1] + v[0])/2) * 2)
        else:
            w = [0 for l in range(n)]
            w[0] = v[0]
            w[1] = int((v[1] + v[0])/2) * 2
            c = 0
            if v[0] % 2:
                c += 1
            if v[1] % 2:
                c += 1
            b = 0
            for k in range(2, n):
                if v[k] % 2:
                    c += 1
                b = int(c // 3)
                if c % 3 == 1:
                    b += 1
                w[k] = (sum(v[:k + 1]) - b)
            print(*w)
```

And here is the code, where I was printing the result of each step within the For loop, hence the time complexity of this code is a pure O(n), since I only go through the given list once:

```
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        n = int(input())
        v = list(map(int, input().split()))
        if n == 1:
            print(v[0])
        elif n == 2:
            print(v[0], int((v[1] + v[0])/2) * 2)
        else:
            w = [0 for x in range(n)]
            w[0] = v[0]
            print(w[0], end=" ")
            w[1] = int((v[1] + v[0])/2) * 2
            print(w[1], end=" ")
            c = 0
            if v[0] % 2:
                c += 1
            if v[1] % 2:
                c += 1
            b = 0
            for k in range(2, n):
                if v[k] % 2:
                    c += 1
                b = int(c // 3)
                if c % 3 == 1:
                    b += 1
                w[k] = (sum(v[:k + 1]) - b)
                if k == n - 1:
                    print(w[k])
                else:
                    print(w[k], end=" ")
```

any suggestions are highly appreciated. It feels like the problem is not in the algorithm itself, but the data structures I used. However, it's just my hunch.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're mistaken about your algorithm being O(n): you call `sum(v[:k+1])` for each `k`, which is O(n^2). You can fix this by keeping a running sum: initialize `total = v[0] + v[1]` in the `else` once you're sure that there are more than two elements, and let `total += v[k]` for each `k` thereafter. Then you can replace the call to `sum` with `total`.
2. This is less important since it doesn't affect the time complexity, but you don't actually need the `w` array. You only ever compute some value, write it to `w[k]`, and then immediately `print(w[k])`, and never read any values back from `w` after that. So you can remove `w` and just print the computed values directly.

I took your code and made only those two changes and submitted it, and it passed with a runtime of 200ms. So Python is just fine. You were making the mistake of recomputing the same sub-problem (sum of the first N elements of an array) over and over.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate it a lot. You are totally right. I can't believe I didn't see that recalculation of the sum myself until you told me about it. Clearly, a fresh pair of eyes are of huge help.